# Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries" launching stack with linux container from docker daemon

Tags: python, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to deploy a python application as a linux container on windows 10. I installed docker desktop with wsl and successively launch docker-compose stack. I created script to be run on system boot by task scheduler:
`docker compose -d`

So, I required to start docker daemon on boot. I found [this article](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/StartDockerDaemonAsAWindowsService.html#:%7E:text=To%20start%20Docker%20in%20daemon,immediately,%20before%20anyone%20logs%20on) which explained how to do this. After this, I tried to launch container. And got the error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  421.8MB
Step 1/14 : FROM python:3.10-bullseye
3.10-bullseye: Pulling from library/python
1 error occurred:
        * Status: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.19044 in the manifest list entries, Code: 1
```

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.10-bullseye
WORKDIR /app
COPY Pipfile Pipfile 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
RUN pip install pipenv 
RUN pipenv install
COPY . .
ENV STREAMLIT_BROWSER_GATHER_USER_STATS=false
ENV STREAMLIT_SERVER_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE=2000
ENV STREAMLIT_SERVER_RUN_ON_SAVE=true
ENV STREAMLIT_SERVER_HEADLESS=true
CMD ["pipenv", "run", "streamlit", "run", "src/main.py"]
EXPOSE 8501
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "1.27.0+"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
       - 8501:8501
```

Comment: If you're trying to build a Linux container, unclear how you're getting `windows/amd64` platform being applied

Comment: That's what I don't understand, too.

Comment: Well, look at the supported platforms for each tag, not all have windows https://hub.docker.com/_/python/tags?page=1&name=3.10

Comment: In the compose file, you should be using `version: "3"` and then you can add `platform` field under your app service to force a linux container. Otherwise, you use `3.10-windowsservercore`, for example

Comment: Is your _host_ Windows/AMD64? Please [edit] to clarify. (The link points to a Windows instruction so I'm guessing that's a yes, but please don't make us guess.)

Comment: @triplee Yes, Windows 10.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Changed what you mentioned, docker behaviour hasn't changed.